# vim-go GoDebugBreakpoint can't toggle

Tags: go, vim

I am using vim-go to debug my go code. When I :GoDebugBreakpoint the '>' sign is shown in left side. But I cannot remove or toggle it. Any Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution from vim-go doc vim-go doc/vim-go.txt[https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/doc/vim-go.txt]. I had to read the help doc of :sign. and used :sign unplace to remove the sign.

Answer (score 0):

tldr;

(https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/doc/vim-go.txt)

FYI:

:GoDebugBreakpoint twice to remove left '>'